# When i create and incident in customer portal the redirection put refno on url

Tags: rightnow-crm, oracle-service-cloud

i'm working on OSC rightnow. I have a form to create an incident:

```
<form id="rn_QuestionSubmit" method="post" action="/ci/ajaxRequest/sendForm">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Rellena los siguientes campos para formalizar la inscripción:</legend>
                    <div id="rn_ErrorLocation"></div>

                    <div class="rn_Hidden">
                        <rn:widget path="input/FormInput" name="Incident.Subject" required="true" label_input="#rn:msg:SUBJECT_LBL#" default_value="Las claves de la Transformación Digital en la relación con el Cliente." />
                        <rn:widget path="input/FormInput" name="Incident.CustomFields.c.partner" required="true"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <rn:widget path="input/FormInput" label_input="Nombre" name="Contact.Name.First" required="true" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <rn:widget path="input/FormInput"  label_input="Apellidos" name="Contact.Name.Last" required="true" />
                        </div>                          
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <rn:widget path="input/FormInput" label_input="Cargo" name="Contact.CustomFields.c.cargo2" required="true" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <rn:widget path="input/FormInput" name="Contact.CustomFields.c.empresa" required="true" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <rn:widget path="input/FormInput" label_input="Email" name="Contact.Emails.PRIMARY.Address" required="true" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <rn:widget path="input/FormInput" label_input="Asistencia" name="Incident.CustomFields.c.interaccion" required="true" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <hr class="blueHr">
                    <rn:widget path="input/FormSubmit" label_button="Confirmar" flash_message="redireccionando..." on_success_url="/app/emailFailed" add_params_to_url="userName,marcos" error_location="rn_ErrorLocation"/>
                    <div class="row informationRights">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <p>
                                La información que aquí nos proporciones será exclusivamente utilizada para mantenerte al corriente sobre novedades de esta jornada. Tienes derecho a acceder a tu registro para rectificarlo o cancelarlo, mediante email a


                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

When I do submit redirect to the correct page (/app/emailFailed) but puts on url a parameter called "refno" how can i modify that and put my own parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The refno field is a standard parameter added to the out-of-the-box controller that your form is submitted to.  If you need to alter the URL parameters, then you'll need to create a custom controller that can perform the action of submitting your form and adding the parameters that you need.  The easiest way to do this would be to create a new controller that subclasses ajaxRequest so that you can override the sendform method with the logic that you need to implement.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't in the controller, but you gave me an idea. The addition of the parameter was done directly in the model and it returned the url to the controller.